# What is a good DVD authoring application for Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, 19.04, dvd

I'm looking for a DVD authoring application for Ubuntu 19.04 DeVeDeNG works, but I'm not happy with the main menu.  Bombono works great in 18.04, but not 19.04.  Any other suggestions for an application that works in 19.04?

The question is not duplicated because it is a question after DVD authoring and not DVD burning.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! there is some good info here: https://www.networkworld.com/article/2292830/136096-Six-free-open-source-CD-and-or-DVD-authoring-tools-for-Linux.html. Also, if you try this command, you will see lots of goodies available in Ubuntu: `apt search dvd|grep -C 3 DVD`

Comment: I was asking about DVD authoring, not DVD burning.  I have raw mp4 video files that I would like to make into a DVD.  Neither Brasero nor K3b, to my knowledge, will take these files and create a DVD with menus, etc.  I mentioned that I used DeVeDe, but I am not happy with the results.  Bombono does not work consistently on Ubuntu 19.04.  I was asking for an alternative to these.  IMO, this is not a duplicate question.  Joshua Besneatte did provide useful information.  In the end I found DVD Styler as a very good application.

Comment: These days you can find the Network World article here: https://web.archive.org/web/20201111214010/https://www.networkworld.com/article/2292830/136096-Six-free-open-source-CD-and-or-DVD-authoring-tools-for-Linux.html#slide1

Answer (score 1):

#### DVDStyler

[DVDStyler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dvdstyler/) is a cross-platform free DVD authoring application that makes possible for video enthusiasts to create professional-looking DVDs. DVDStyler provides over 20 DVD menu templates, allowing you to create your own menu designs and photo slideshows. After you select your DVD label name, video quality, video format, aspect ratio, and audio format, you can select a template to add video materials to. DVDStyler's interface supports drag-and-drop so you can add project buttons and movies around with ease. Some basic video editing operations such as trimming and cropping are also available.

The main features of DVDStyler are:

- create and burn DVD video with interactive menus
- support of AVI, MOV, MP4, MPEG, OGG, WMV and other file formats
- support of MPEG-2, MPEG-4, DivX, Xvid, MP2, MP3, AC-3 and other audio and video formats
- user-friendly interface with support of drag-and-drop
- flexible menu creation on the basis of scalable vector graphics
  file

To install DVDStyler dwonload the DVDStyler .tar.bz2 file and follow the instructions in [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/25961/).

---

#### Open DVD Producer

Open DVD Producer (*opendvdproducer*) is a modern, open source cross platform software to produce DVD images, and create DVDs with menus and chapters in a simple yet professional way. The main functions of the DVD specification are implemented in the software. For example, you can create a DVD in any supported format, with various menus, with directional buttons, videos with chapters and set sections of videos to play.

The main features of Open DVD Producer are:

- **Menus** - You can create static menus with any sound you want. Or you can use some special video as animated menu.
- **Buttons** - "Point and click" the buttons you want to create, and you have a real time preview of them. Also, you can set the directions the remote control will take.
- **Built-in encoder** - There is no need to use some external conversor. Open DVD Producer is able to convert from any kind of known video format.
- **Chapters** - Want to play at some point in the video? No problem, you can set chapter marks directly on the timeline, and also set segmented pieces of video.
- **MD5 checksum** - Generate MD5 after the ISO is ready for integrity check.
- **DDP® for replication** - The DDP® can be generated for large production (specification version 2.00).
- **Advanced settings for menus** - You can set the background image or video. The color and opacity of buttons highlight. Set the buttons directions directly on the screen.
- **Advanced settings for videos** - It is possible to set the video resolution. Also you can set chapter marks in a visual way, with frame-by-frame accuracy.

To install Open DVD Producer in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install opendvdproducer --channel=edge
```

---

#### Bombono DVD

Bombono DVD works great in 18.04, but not 19.04. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install bombono-dvd bombono-dvd-data
```

Answer (score 0):

DeVeDe, DeVeDeNG - The Menu is not as pretty as in bonbono DVD but works with any format and on any version of Ubuntu (from 10.10 to 20x). Supports all kernels

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could install DVDStyler in (now up to) 20.10.  One has to install dev versions of the some of the libraries.  This requires examining the outputs at each stage, then installing the dev libraries.

Alternatively, I found I could install the windows version (.exe) of DVDStyler using wine, and it works fine.